# Changing query params and pass to other .cgi file executed by eval do in perl

Tags: perl, cgi, eval

I am working on perl CGI file which calls to another .CGI file with the help of  eval do{} 
now i tried to change query params and append one more parameter to list of query params with the help of below code:

```
file1.cgi use CGI;
    my $q = CGI->new();
    $q->param(-value=>'new value', -name=>'field1'); #appending query param

    my $field1 = $query->param('field1');
    print "===> $field1 <==="; #prints the value of field1

    open MACROFILE,"<file2.cgi" or print "Could not open file";
    my $mstatus = eval do{local $/;<MACROFILE>} or print $@; ## passing content of file to eval
    close MACROFILE;
```

**Below is the code in file2.cgi which is getting executed in eval:**

```
file2.cgi:
    use CGI;
    my $query = new CGI;
    my $field1 = $query->param('field1');
    print "===> $field1 <==="; #Empty value since "field1" in not found in query params
```

why appended query params are not getting cached, is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

As file2.cgi is a CGI program, it expects to be called as a CGI program - i.e. using a HTTP request. Of course you can't just `eval` the file and expect it to work.

Is there a good reason why file2.cgi needs to be a CGI program? Does it live on another server or something like that? If that's the case, then you should call it doing something like this:

```
use LWP::Simple;

my $response = get("http://your-server.com/file2.cgi?field1=new+value");
```

But if you're just calling a program on the same server, you can just call it using `system()`.

```
# Renamed the file as it's no longer a CGI program
system('/path/to/file2.pl', 'new value');
```

In this case, you'll need to rewrite file2 so that it reads its arguments from the command like.

```
my $field1 = @ARGV[0];
```

But perhaps I'm completely misunderstanding and you have a good reason for taking the baroque approach that you're trying here.

Comment: Both files are on same server,but if i can append some parameters in query params on file1.cgi, and i try to catch newly added params using `$query->param('field1');` on **file1.cgi** so why these newly added params not getting cached in **file2.cgi** ?

Comment: Well, as I said, because you're not calling file2.cgi correctly.